# Projective tensor squares of uniform algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

In discussion with a colleague recently (Jan 2017),
$\newcommand{\AD}{A({\bf D})}\newcommand{\CT}{C({\bf T})}$
 I was reminded that if $A(D)$ denotes the disc algebra and $\iota: \AD\to \CT$ is the standard isometric embedding, then 
$$\iota\otimes\iota : \AD\hat\otimes\AD \to \CT\hat\otimes\CT$$
has closed range. Since $\AD$ is not complemented as a Banach space in $\CT$ this is far from obvious, and to my knowledge the only proofs go via a version for $\AD$ of Grothendieck's theorem/inequality, established originally by Bourgain in the 1980s.

Many years ago I was interested in what was known for other uniform algebras. My recollection is that if one replaces $\AD$ with the polydisc algebra or the ball algebra in $n$ dimensions, $n\geq 2$, then it was unknown if the corresponding map $\iota\otimes\iota$ into the appropriate $C(K)\hat\otimes C(K)$ has closed range.

**Q1.** Is it known by now if the corresponding result for polydisc algebras or ball algebras is *false*?

**Q2.** Are there any other examples known where the analogous result is true? (Obviously one could do trivial modifications of the disc algebra case by taking a uniform algebra that contains a finite-codimension closed copy of $\AD$; I mean genuinely new examples such as $R(K)$ for other domains.)